# configure minikube / kubernetes webhook authentication / authorization

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, minikube

I'd like to enable kubernetes webhook token authentication.
I'm expecting to get it working exactly the way it is described in official documentation
[webhook-token-authentication](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#webhook-token-authentication)

however since i'm complete newbie to kubernetes i'm struggling  to understand what steps should i take in order to achive my aim.

precondition: i'm using minikube to test it locally.

documentation says that i have to use `--authentication-token-webhook-config-file` but i don't understand basic things such as:

1. where do i place file with authorization config ?
2. how to supply above parameter to minikube?
   (If i run `minikube start --help` it doesn't seem support this flag.)
3. how do i enable `authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1` for minikube apiserver (required step)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few steps which i taken to tackle this

**1. Create valid yaml or json config files pointing to your auth/authz services.**

**2. Make sure your services running via `https` protocol**
*(neither minikube nor kubernetes will work through `http`)*

> Dummy but simple way is to use [Ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) which gives you `https` uri which route to service running on your machine.
>
> the command will look like `ngrok protocol port` -> `ngrok http 4567`

**3. Finally start minikube using command**

> minikube start
>   --extra-config apiserver.Authentication.WebHook.ConfigFile=/Users/username/auth.yml
>   --extra-config apiserver.Authorization.Mode=Webhook
>   --extra-config apiserver.Authorization.WebhookConfigFile=/Users/username/authz.yml

*Note: By default minikube mounts your `Users` directory therefore you can access config files over the /Users/username/path-to-file.yml*

**4. At last add test-user to your kube config file with no certificates and try it out.**
run `kubectl --context minikube-auth-test get pods`
If everything was setup correctly you'll get post requests to your auth/authz services

Answer (score 0):

Note that authentication ("authN") is a separate step from authorization ("authZ"). You are conflating both here but you don't necessarily have to do so - i.e. you can use a webhook authentication server, and then the usual RBAC authorization by attach policies to the user identified by your authentication step.

> 1. where do i place file with authorization config ?

This is a slightly tricky step that I don't think is well documented in the minikube docs. You need to keep in mind that the `kube-apiserver` pod that minikube spins up for you runs in its own container, and therefore doesn't have access to the same filesystem you see when doing e.g. `minikube ssh`. You need to mount in your `authn.yaml` config file as a volume - see https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/2767#issuecomment-437299401 for more on this.

> 2. how to supply above parameter to minikube? (If i run minikube start --help it doesn't seem support this flag.)

```
minikube start \
  --extra-config=apiserver.authentication-token-webhook-config-file=/path/on/host/to/authn.yaml
```

Remember as I mentioned above that `/path/on/host` does *not* refer to your host machine (your laptop, desktop, workstation) but rather to the minikube host VM.

> 3. how do i enable `authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1`

```
minikube start \
  --extra-config=apiserver.authentication-token-webhook-version=authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the sample auth webhook repo to get the steps.
https://github.com/dinumathai/auth-webhook-sample#deploy-in-minikube

If you face any issue in starting the minikube. Do "minikube ssh" and "docker log" of the api server container.